# Retrieve Starting and Ending values from a table whose values have gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I retrieve the values from a table where there are TicketType and TicketNo columns. Each TicketType can have mutiple TicketNos and these TicketNos may have gaps between them. TicketNos are not generated by the system. Not my choice. Here is a sample of the data and the desired output:

```
    declare @tickets table ( TicketType varchar(20), 
                         TicketNo int )
insert into @tickets( tickettype, ticketno )
select 'AIRCON 1', 1 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 1', 2 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 1', 3 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 1', 6 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 1', 7 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 1', 8 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 1', 9 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 2', 1 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 2', 2 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 2', 3 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 2', 4 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 2', 5 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 3', 1 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 3', 2 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 3', 9 
union all 
select 'AIRCON 3', 10 

select * from @tickets

SELECT 'AIRCON 1' TicketType, 1 Starting, 3 Ending 
union all
select 'AIRCON 1', 6, 9
union all 
select 'AIRCON 2', 1, 5
union all
select 'AIRCON 3', 1, 2
union all
select 'AIRCON 3', 9, 10
```

Sample data:

```
+------------------------------------+
|   TicketType           TicketNo    |
+------------------------------------+
| AIRCON 1             1             |
| AIRCON 1             2             |
| AIRCON 1             3             |
| AIRCON 1             6             |
| AIRCON 1             7             |
| AIRCON 1             8             |
| AIRCON 1             9             |
| AIRCON 2             1             |
| AIRCON 2             2             |
| AIRCON 2             3             |
| AIRCON 2             4             |
| AIRCON 2             5             |
| AIRCON 3             1             |
| AIRCON 3             2             |
| AIRCON 3             9             |
| AIRCON 3             10            |
```

Desired Result

```
| TicketType Starting    Ending      |
| ---------- ----------- ----------- |
| AIRCON 1   1           3           |
| AIRCON 1   6           9           |
| AIRCON 2   1           5           |
| AIRCON 3   1           2           |
| AIRCON 3   9           10          |
+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you also include sample data and expected result in tabular format. Doing so adds to the readability of your question as it makes it easier to the reader to understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Rather than showing us the `INSERT` statements, it would be more helpful if you showed us the data in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is variation of islands problem.

```
select TicketType, min(ticketno), max(ticketno)
from (
    select TicketType, ticketno, row_number() over( partition by tickettype order by ticketno) - ticketno grp
    from @tickets
) t
group by TicketType, grp
order by TicketType, min(ticketno)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the grouping column (root) for islands in your data. Like this:

```
;with cteMain as (
    select
        *
        , lag(t.TicketNo, 1, -1) over (order by t.TicketType, t.TicketNo) as TicketNoLag
    from @tickets t
), cteHierarchy as (
    select
        m.TicketType
        , m.TicketNo
        , m.TicketNoLag
        , m.TicketNo as Root
    from cteMain m
    where m.TicketNo - m.TicketNoLag <> 1
    union all
    select
        m.TicketType
        , m.TicketNo
        , m.TicketNoLag
        , h.Root as Root
    from cteMain m
        inner join cteHierarchy h on m.TicketNoLag = h.TicketNo
            and m.TicketType = h.TicketType
            and m.TicketNo - m.TicketNoLag = 1
)
select
    h.TicketType
    , min(h.TicketNo) as Starting
    , max(h.TicketNo) as Ending
from cteHierarchy h
group by h.TicketType, h.Root
order by h.TicketType
```